# How can I create custom login page URLs in Rails/Devise for partner links?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url, devise

I have a Rails 4 application using Devise for authentication.

In addition to the standard Devise login page, I want to have partner login pages that basically look and function the same way, but have a unique URL, like:

http://example.com/partner1

What is the best way to do this?  I'm not sure how the routes file should look.  And is using FriendlyID a good idea as well?

I have a PartnerPage model in the database which contains a "link" field, which is where the admin will enter the link/partner code.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a custom route to the signup form is pretty straight forward:

```
get '/partner1', to: 'devise/sessions#new'
```

However if you want to have a customized login screen a good solution is to subclass `Devise::SessionsController`.

```
# app/controllers/partner1/sessions_controller.rb
class Partner1::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController; end
```

and in your routes:

```
get '/partner1', to: 'partner1/sessions#new'
```

This will render `app/veiws/partner1/sessions/new.html.erb`.

Comment: Friendly ID is totally irrelevant to this question - its is for creating vanity urls based things like user names instead of the ID attribute.